# Make my table sortable by four columns

Tags: php, postgresql, sorting

I have a user log table that works fine and is sorted by timestamp, but I also need it sortable by IP ADDRESS and USER but can't get it working properly. I want the user to be able to choose a column to ORDER BY and the whole table will resort by that column. I found a solution using libraries but I can't do it that way, I need something simple and standalone. Please assist.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr bgcolor="#D4E9FC">
<td> 
Timestamp 
<a href="?OrderBy=user_log.stamp&SortBy=DESC">&#9660;</a>
<a href="?OrderBy=user_log.stamp&SortBy=ASC">&#9650;</a> 
</td> 
<td> 
User
<a href="?OrderBy=user_staff.user_name&SortBy=DESC">&#9660;</a>
<a href="?OrderBy=user_staff.user_name&SortBy=ASC">&#9650;</a>
</td>
<td> 
IP Address
<a href="?OrderBy=user_log.userip&SortBy=DESC">&#9660;</a> 
<a href="?OrderBy=user_log.userip&SortBy=ASC">&#9650;</a>
</td> 
<td> 
Transfer
<a href="?OrderBy=user_log.transfer_id&SortBy=DESC">&#9660;</a> 
<a href="?OrderBy=user_log.transfer_id&SortBy=ASC">&#9650;</a>
</td> 
<td> 
Action
</td> 
</tr>
```

```
    $orderBy = array('user_log.stamp&SortBy=DESC', 'user_staff.user_name&SortBy=DESC', 'user_log.userip&SortBy=DESC', 'user_log.transfer_id&SortBy=DESC');

    $order = 'user_log.stamp';
if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
$order = $_GET['orderBy']  . ' ' . $_GET['SortBy'];
}

 $query = "SELECT user_log.stamp, user_staff.user_name, user_log.userip, user_log.transfer_id, user_log.action
    FROM user_log
    INNER JOIN user_staff
    ON user_staff.user_id=user_log.user_id 
    ORDER BY $order
    LIMIT 200";

    $result = pg_query($query); 
    if (!$result) { 
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>"; 
        echo pg_last_error(); 
        exit(); 
    } 

    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $myrow['stamp'], htmlspecialchars($myrow['user_name']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['userip']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['transfer_id']), htmlspecialchars($myrow['action']));
    } 
    ?>
    </table><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make table like this:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr bgcolor="#D4E9FC">
    <td> 
    Timestamp 
    <a href="?OrderBy=user_log.stamp&SortBy=DESC">&darr;</a> 
    <a href="?OrderBy=user_log.stamp&SortBy=ASC">&uarr;</a>
    </td> 
    <td> 
    User
    <a href="?OrderBy=user_staff.user_name&SortBy=DESC">&darr;</a> 
    <a href="?OrderBy=user_staff.user_name&SortBy=ASC">&uarr;</a>
    </td>
    <td> 
    IP Address
    <a href="?OrderBy=user_log.userip&SortBy=DESC">&darr;</a> 
    <a href="?OrderBy=user_log.userip&SortBy=ASC">&uarr;</a>
    </td> 
    <td> 
    Transfer
    </td> 
    <td> 
    Action
    </td> 
</tr>
<table>
```

then i php you can find GET params:

```
$orderBy = 'user_log.stamp';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    $orderBy = isset($_GET['OrderBy']) ? $_GET['OrderBy'] : 'user_log.stamp';
    $orderBy = isset($_GET['SortBy']) ? $_GET['SortBy'] : 'DESC';

}
     $query = "SELECT user_log.stamp, user_staff.user_name, user_log.userip, user_log.transfer_id, user_log.action
            FROM user_log
            INNER JOIN user_staff
            ON user_staff.user_id=user_log.user_id 
            ORDER BY $orderBy 
            DESC LIMIT 200";
```

I was using your logic - but what are you doing is not save at all... Better is use PDO statements!

Comment: This works well except need to leave out DESC in the SQL because it comes through the GET

Comment: And this bit doesn't work for the initial table, so the table only populates after an arrow is clicked, otherwise get syntax error if (!$orderBy) {
$orderBy = 'user_log.stamp';
}

Comment: I have modified the question to add in what you gave me and to make it more secure

Comment: Glad I can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work:

```
$query = "SELECT user_log.stamp, user_staff.user_name, user_log.userip, user_log.transfer_id, user_log.action
        FROM user_log
        INNER JOIN user_staff
        ON user_staff.user_id=user_log.user_id 
        ORDER BY user_log.stamp DESC, user_log.userip DESC, user_staff.user_name ASC  
        LIMIT 200";
```

Comment: No, I can do that, but I need it like excel where they can sort by column if they want for those three columns. Instead of sql just sorting once.